# Numeric Field in PDF Form changes numeric value in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdf, livecycle-designer

I'm using an Adobe Form created in Livecycle ES2 and a PHP script to enter data into a mysql database.  For some reason the number I enter into the form and the number being sent via $_POST are different.  I have never come across this before.  Can anyone let me know why this is happening.  I'm able to change the form field to text and it works fine though then I also have to change the db field to varchar which isn't really the proper way of storing a number.

I also need to add some of the numeric fields together and I don't want unintended consequences by changing the numeric fields to text fields.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Justin

Comment: without seeing your code it's impossible to do anything other than wild guess. Does the var name in the form match your POST exactly?

Comment: James, I really have no idea what you are talking about.  It's simple.  Numeric field -> Submit using URL-Encode in PDF Form -> Post number is different.  Why would the $_Post info be different if it's a numeric format being passed to POST array???  I'm not sure what "code" you are looking for here exactly o_O  The code is pretty simple objectNameFromPDFform is passed into the POST array and I'm collecting that number submitting to a MySQL database.  I'm not sure how much "clearer" I can be without posting ALL of the xml from the PDF form.

Comment: I figured it out.  You have to change the numeric field from integer to float or it changes the number when it's being passed to the $_POST[]  I have no idea why this would happen...guessing it's something to do with how Acrobat passes the information to POST.  Anyways, if someone else runs into this just change the numeric field to a float and it works fine.